# What is the worst case scenario for next fit bin packing?

Tags: algorithms, approximation

So I know the Next Fit Bin Packing algorithm is bounded by two times the optimal solution for the problem, but I can not think of an order of arriving elements that actually takes twice the number of bins necessary.

Something like:

50 -> 25 -> 50 -> 25 -> 50 -> 25 -> 50 -> 25

would result in:

|25| |25| |25| |25|

|50| |50| |50| |50|

bins with next fit while the optimal solution would be:

|50| |50| |25 * 2|

|50| |50| |25 * 2|

Which is only one bin difference.
So what actually is the worst order of elements for the next fit bin packing algorithm?

Comment: A _bound_ is not the same as a _tight bound_.  Not saying that it's not tight, just saying that it's an upper bound.  For example, for knapsack, the easy proof for the "next fit" heuristic gives a factor two bound, but a slightly more involved proof gives something like a factor 3/2 upper bound.

Comment: This may be helpful http://www.labri.fr/perso/eyraud/pmwiki/uploads/Main/BinPackingSurvey.pdf. See figure 2.1

Comment: @PålGD Make an answer?